# Is there a simpler method to write this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query in MySQL that does some authentication checks, but it's quite long. I'm wondering whether there would be another method to shorten/simplify it, but all clauses are actually required.

```
select nickname from nicknames where nickname = '$nick' and password = '$md5pass' 
union 
select '$nick' as nickname from nicknames AS t1 where not 
  (nickname = '$nick' and password = '$md5pass') 
and not exists 
  (select 1 from nicknames where nickname = '$nick')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select coalesce(max(nickname), '$nick')
from nicknames
where nickname = '$nick' and password = '$md5pass';
```

Comment: This doesn't work the same. It returns a row when no password is supplied but the nickname is present.